# mplayer over 2 screens

Tags: video, fullscreen, mplayer, twinview

I recently found an mplayer command line example that plays a video over 2 screens (nvidia twinview)

but I lost it somehow.

So does anyone know how to play a video with mplayer and have it stretch over both screens?

Comment: the feature you are looking for is called Video Wall. I know VLC also supports it. anyway, if you look for mplayer video wall. hope it helps

Comment: Indeed, VLC has it, and it works pretty well.